# Notifications causing screen waking

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, notifications, power-management

I recently got a new MacBook Pro (2019 model). With this computer, if the displays are sleeping (I often have an external monitor attached via USB-C dock), they will wake up for a few seconds when a notification comes in, and then they go back into power-saving mode. My previous MBP (late 2013 model) did not have this problem. I call it a problem as the computer is in my bedroom, and the momentary flash of light is waking me up sometimes at night. How can I stop this from happening? (Both Macs are running 10.14.6)

Comment: Have you tried using Do Not Disturb during these hours?

Comment: @fsb DND is not on - I will try that this evening. (Although that wasn't on on my previous MBP...)

Comment: You could turn off Power nap too

Comment: @ankii Power Nap isn't applicable here - the MBP is not asleep, but awake with screen savers on.

Comment: @fsb I checked the "Turn on Do Not Disturb: When the display is sleeping" option and that seems to have done the trick. If you'd like to answer this question I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on Do Not Disturb ("DND") mode to prevent distractions or notifications during specific timeframes.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl999b7c1a/10.14/mac/10.14):

### Schedule Do Not Disturb

1. On your Mac, choose `Apple menu  > System Preferences` or open "System Preferences" directly from the icon.
2. Click "Notifications".
3. Select "Do Not Disturb" at the top of the sidebar.

You can stop notifications during a time period, when your Mac is in sleep (useful if you sleep near your Mac) by checking the "When the display is sleeping" box.

[image]

If you want to receive call notifications even when Do Not Disturb is on, select the call checkboxes.